# how can i create copy pointer to NSArray if my class is singleton class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a singleton class. In this class, i am holding an array of songs. This array should not change! in my app when i choose a song from my song list, the current song is inserted to another variable. This var is Song type ( the array is array of songs ). so when i am writing

```
_myDataMgr._currSong = [_myDataMgr.songArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

Every time i will change this currSong Variable the songArray will change because currSong is point to this array. so my question is how i can create a copy of this currSong? i know somthing about `NSCopy` but i dont know how to use it really. thank you all.
P.S: `_myDataMgr` is the singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your class conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

```
@interface Song : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

Then, implement the method `copyWithZone:`

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];

    if (copy) {
        // Copy properties here...
    }

    return copy;
}
```

When you need a copy of your instance, just call `copy`. *(I recommend to call this when you're inserting the songs into the array in the singleton class.)*

```
[myArray insertObject:[song copy]];
```

Comment: wow that was fast :) but how i can use it? call this method when i need to create the copy? ( i need to insert only in specific press )